# google maps add single marker on click don't works

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've googled and searched deeply in stackoverflow with no results.

i have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.47554, 9.204712),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoomControl: true
        });


    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
        alert("click");
    });

</script>
```

and when I click on map I haven't the alert. Where am I wrong please? Thank you.

Comment: sorry, I can't answer my own post, I've solved it, but no way to add a marker..

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `no way to add a marker`, in this case to add a marker in the map you can use following code

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        // options
    });

    // Add a marker at center/current latlng
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        map: map,
        title: 'Some Title'
    });

    // To add a click event on the marker you can use
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        // ...
    });
}
```

[Read more.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)